# Android roboquice transient dependency

Tags: java, android, maven, jenkins

I got that error from `jenkins` running `mvn clean install` on Parent `pom`. But I can not reproduce it on my local env because when I run it on local everything works fine. Maybye someone had such problem. Thanks in advance for your advices.

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:apk (default-apk) on project RondoAndroid: Error while processing transient dependencies: Failed to collect dependencies at org.roboguice:roboguice:jar:3.0b-experimental -> android.support:compatibility-v4:jar:11: Failed to read artifact descriptor for android.support:compatibility-v4:jar:11: Could not transfer artifact android.support:compatibility-v4:pom:11 from/to third.party.closed.source.repo (file://${basedir}/../maven_repo_3rd_party): Repository path /../maven_repo_3rd_party does not exist, and cannot be created.`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote email to the author of RoboGuice. He said that `3.0b-experimental` should be replaced by `2.0` version. This is stable version valid for use. After I apply that solution everythink works fine. I hope that might help somebody.